# Этот кот (–) ни о чём, то бишь беспонтовый

Tags: пунктуация

В правилах, то бишь в 14-м параграфе, говорится – http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.phpsid=106#pp106, – что, если сказуемое – фразеологизм, но есть *не*, тире лучше не ставить (но можно). Однако есть фразеологизм *ни о чём*. Если он является сказуемым, то надо ли ставить тире?

`Этот кот (–) ни о чём, то бишь беспонтовый.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

*Этот кОт – **ни о чём,** то бишь беспонтовый.*

Выражение ***«ни о чём»*** обозначает «то, что не заслуживает внимания; пустяк; что-либо некачественное (разг.)».

В данном случае устойчивое выражение является **сказуемым** и его желательно отделить от подлежащего. Обычно тире не ставится **в таких сочетаниях:** *Грош цена теории,* которая фиксирует одни шаблоны (Гол.); *Два сапога пара* (Погов.).  В этом случае **все предложение** является фразеологизмом.

При постановке тире подлежащее будет логически **подчеркнуто** ударением.

Comment: А правда, что, если *не* есть, можно всё равно ставить тире, или это Лопатин просто намудрил, сказав, что *не* тире не запрещает?

Comment: Там написано так: "Наличие частицы не, а также вводных слов при устойчивых сочетаниях в роли сказуемого препятствует постановке тире (но не запрещает)". Если есть НЕ или вводное слово, то тире обычно не ставится, но может быть поставлено (интонационное тире при наличии паузы).